# Why my systemctl v208 command doesn't support some features?

Tags: debian, systemd

I'm presuming there's a patch somewhere where Debian decided to disable it, but I can't find it nor the changelog entry. There are several commands that aren't available, like `dot`, `dump`, `list-timers` and others more nifty. Where are them? `systemctl --help` also doesn't list them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list-timers` arrived with v209.

`dump` moved to `systemd-analyze` with v207.

`dot` moved to `systemd-analyze` with v198.

All the above came from `systemd`'s [NEWS](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/NEWS) file.